# Naming breakpoints in GDB

Tags: gdb

Is there anyway to name a breakpoint in GDB so when it is hit GDB gives some name instead of a number? (IE hit breakpoint !!!VERYIMPORTANTBREAKPOINT!!! in method main())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to name a break point in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582577/is-it-possible-to-name-a-break-point-in-gdb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, there is no way to do this, but you can use the 'commands' command, and the print command.

e.g.

```
break main
commands
print "!!!VERYIMPORTANTBREAKPOINT!!! in method main()"
end
```