# Is it possible to name a break point in GDB?

Tags: gdb

Is there any way to label/name breakpoints in GDB, in order to more easily identify them in, for instance, `info b`? And if so, how?

Comment: Thanks, not a very useful work around though. I'm looking for a way to label them in the output of `info b`, not just when they are hit.

Comment: Someone must python script this up :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~adnan/gdb-refcard.pdf

Comment: Sorry, I know it was a short question, but a short absolute answer with no reference is not helpful.

Comment: Updated with a link to support this. The answer still doesn't change that its not supported. Kudos for finding the old post regarding the 'commands' command. There was no reason to downvote the correct answer to the question.

Comment: I do think this is something they should support though, when working with multiple breakpoints and files its really handy to have something more than a line number, maybe it should be suggested to GNU

Comment: @ChrisWhite: I removed the down vote since you provided a reference. I down voted it originally because it was a poor answer, not because I didn't like the conclusion. If you had answered "yes it is possible" but not described how to do it or provided a reference, I would have downvoted that as well. Bare assertions are not helpful on SO.

Answer (score 3):

While this doesn't help with the output of `info b`, for other purposes where you need to reference the breakpoint later in commands you can store the breakpoint number of the last breakpoint from `$bpnum` in another convenience variable, e.g.:

```
b foo.c:123
set $im_a_breakpoint = $bpnum
# ... set some more breakpoints and do some other stuff ...
disable $im_a_breakpoint
```

As a further example, I'm using this pattern right now for a task: I'm using normal gdb breakpoints in code emitted by a JIT, which requires setting the breakpoint on the address after the code has actually been emitted as gdb modifies the code.  For this purpose I actually disable the initial set-up breakpoint from within its own `commands` block:

```
set $cur_stop_point = 0x41aaa
b basic_jit_cache::copy_block if ((uint32_t)this->code_ptr()) > ($gencode + $cur_stop_point)
set $cur_stop_point_setup_bp = $bpnum
commands
  b *($gencode + $cur_stop_point)
  disable $cur_stop_point_setup_bp
  cont
end
```